Applying gradient boosted trees to a linear combination of labels
Given a set of features $X$, and three set of labels $y_1, y_2$ and $y_1+y_2$, we fit 3 gradient boosted regressors on the training data and get the functions, $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$. Does $f_1(X)+f_2(X) = f_3(X)$ or does the equality hold with very small errors? Since GBMs break down the label values to smaller values and simpler trees predict each piece and then the final result is the sum of prediction of these smaller pieces, one might expect this equality might hold in general. (But of course this argument does not produce any proofs.)
Another practical way to reformulate the question, is that assuming that the models $f_1$ and $f_2$ are very good models that generalize well to the test set, does it imply that $f_3$ also should be a good model too? is it possible to get good models for $f_1$ and $f_2$ but a terrible one for $f_3$ that does not generalize well?

Actual equality certainly doesn't hold in most cases. A GBM regressor (with its identity link function) is just the sum of its component trees, so if you just union the trees from the two models you would get the same result. But training a GBM from scratch, the trees will make splits to target the combined residuals, so you generally won't recreate the two sets of trees.
I think $f_1+f_2\approx f_3$ should hold for most real-life datasets, but that this cannot be guaranteed (depending I suppose on how you parametrize "$\approx$").  And this doesn't really depend on GBMs.  Let $y_1, y_2$ be independent, and let
$$
\begin{align}
x_3&=y_1+y_2=y_3,\\
 x_1&=y_1+\varepsilon_1, \\
x_2&=y_2+\varepsilon_2,
\end{align}
$$
with $\varepsilon_i$ random noise.  Then $f_3$ will be nearly perfect, using $x_3$. But $f_1$ cannot separate out the random noise ($x_3-x_2=y_1-\varepsilon_2$ or just $x_1=y_1+\varepsilon_1$).
